# sphinx search field weights

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, sphinx

I am getting a syntax error on my query in my .conf file
Everything worked great until I added the OPTION field_weights. What am I doing wrong for defining my field weights?

here is the query for my sphinx index

```
source tx3nh_users : src {

    sql_query_range = SELECT MIN(id), MAX(id) FROM tx3nh_users
    sql_query = SELECT u.id, p.fullname, p.email, s.staff_title, s.bio FROM tx3nh_users AS u LEFT JOIN tx3nh_user_attributes AS p ON u.id=p.internalKey LEFT JOIN oxv5v_su_staff AS s ON u.id=s.user_id WHERE u.id>=$start AND u.id<=$end OPTION field_weights=(p.fullname=3, s.staff_title=2, s.bio=1)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sql_query` is a SQL query that indexer runs against your actual database. So it needs to be a valid **MySQL query**. Its intrepreted and executed by MySQL, to return your actual data, which then indexer turns into a sphinx index.

On the other hand `OPTION field_weights` is from **sphinxQL**. So you add it to the SphinxQL query, when you make an actaul query against the index.

```
sphinxQL> SELECT id FROM tx3nh_users WHERE MATCH('keyword1') 
             OPTION field_weights=(p.fullname=3, s.staff_title=2, s.bio=1)
```

Because its a query time paramater the weights arent written to the index, and so you can choose the weights on a per query basis, rather than the same weights for all queries.

Comment: awesome thanks so much! This is a very clear explanation